# Pandas DF Drop duplicates based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
data = pd.DataFrame({

    "a":["123","123","456","456"],
    
    "b":["12-09-23","13-09-23","12-09-23","13-09-23"],
    "c":["abc","xyz","xyz","cde"]

})
```

I want to dedupe the data based on date and retain the record with latest date. However if my column C contains xyz in that case i need to retain the record evne though the date is not latest.

My desired output is

[image]

Comment: Follow the duplicate. Make sure to use a datetime type.

Comment: @mozway I wouldn't need to take the max date. I would need date filter but if the column C has xyz the date filter should not be considered.

Comment: I see, then indeed you need a slightly more complex logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the values by date and equality to "xyz" (with [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)) and get the last value per group with [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html):

```
out = (data
 .iloc[np.lexsort([pd.to_datetime(data['b'], format='%d-%m-%y'),
                   data['c'].eq('xyz')])]
 .groupby('a', as_index=False).last()
)
```

Output:

```
     a         b    c
0  123  13-09-23  xyz
1  456  12-09-23  xyz
```

Comment: @EashwarGV btw, if you have known categories in c, you can also use an ordered Categorical and `sort_values` ;)